# iOS 6: Get strings into array from file line by line

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, file, import

I searched the web but everything I can find doesn't work because it uses old code or something...

1. What filetype would you choose to import a list of words? txt? (about 200 words)
2. How can I get all of the words out of the file and into an array?

I want to output a random word out of the file into a label.

I tried:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
NSArray *arr = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

self.biglabel.text = arr[arc4random() % arr.count];
```

Thanks in advance!
Michael

edit:
works now. I didn't have plain txt files. I renamed a rtf file and that didn't work.

XCode 4.3.3

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: why arr[3] you said random, so it should be  `arr[arc4random%arr.count]`

Comment: What you have seems like a working solution.  Those messages aren't deprecated thus they aren't 'old'. Take anoop's advice with regard to randomness.

Comment: hm ok maybe the problem is somewhere else. I'll take a look and write everything here. And the random thing was supposed to come afterwards^^

Comment: found the problem... I saved the file as rtf with TextEdit and then simply renamed it to txt... now that was just stupid. Got it now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could store it as a [plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) and then turn that directly into an array.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray* arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Your plist would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <string>...</string>
        ...
    </array>
</plist>
```